# Why cant select variables from listbox like this in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, listbox

Hey guys I want to select some variable from the "Variable(s)" listbox to the "Row" and/or "Column" listbox.

[image]

I know I should write like this:

```
   For irow = lbxVar.ListCount To 1 Step -1
        If lbxVar.Selected(irow - 1) = True Then
        lbxColumn.AddItem lbxVar.List(irow - 1)
        lbxVar.RemoveItem (irow - 1)
  End If
Next irow
```

> I just don't understand why I cannot write the code like this?

```
If lbxVar.ListIndex > -1 Then
    For irow = 0 To lbxVar.ListCount - 1
        If lbxVar.Selected(irow) = True Then
        lbxColumn.AddItem lbxVar.List(irow)
        lbxVar.RemoveItem (irow)
    End If
Next irow
End If
```

It showed error:
[image]

Thanks you.

Comment: What's the value of `irow` when the runtime error occurs?

Comment: Side note, you don't need to do `If {bool} = True Then`. Just do `If {bool} Then` instead.

Comment: the second code must bee a for loop from max to min or removeitem will make the error occur at next step of the loop (listcount will be 1 less in real and you try to read data that don't exist anymore)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you have to loop over the collection backwards is because when you remove an item from the list, `lbxVar.ListCount` gets smaller.

However, in a For loop, the number of iterations is fixed after it begins executing - the expression `lbxVar.ListCount - 1` is only evaluated once.  What happens is that if any items are removed, you overrun the bounds of the `lbxVar.Selected`.

When you loop backwards you don't have this problem, because it only changes the indexes of items that you've already iterated over.  If the order that they are added to the second Listbox is what you are trying to preserve by going through the index forward instead of backward, you'll have to loop over the Selected items twice - once to copy to the other Listbox, and once to delete them:

```
If lbxVar.ListIndex > -1 Then
    'Add pass:
    For irow = 0 To lbxVar.ListCount - 1
        If lbxVar.Selected(irow) Then
            lbxColumn.AddItem lbxVar.List(irow)
        End If
    Next irow
    'Remove pass:
    For irow = lbxVar.ListCount To 1 Step -1
        If lbxVar.Selected(irow - 1) Then
            lbxVar.RemoveItem (irow - 1)
        End If
    Next irow
End If
```